# Back-to-top button is glitching when smooth-scrolling is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this code online for a Back To Top Button. It works really well on the website.

```
// Set a variable for our button element.
const scrollToTopButton = document.getElementById('js-top');

// Let's set up a function that shows our scroll-to-top button if we scroll beyond the height of the initial window.
const scrollFunc = () => {
  // Get the current scroll value
  let y = window.scrollY;

  // If the scroll value is greater than the window height, let's add a class to the scroll-to-top button to show it!
  if (y > 100) {
    scrollToTopButton.className = "top-link show";
  } else {
    scrollToTopButton.className = "top-link hide";
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunc);

const scrollToTop = () => {
  // Let's set a variable for the number of pixels we are from the top of the document.
  const c = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

  // If that number is greater than 0, we'll scroll back to 0, or the top of the document.
  // We'll also animate that scroll with requestAnimationFrame:
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame
  if (c > 0) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollToTop);
    // ScrollTo takes an x and a y coordinate.
    // Increase the '10' value to get a smoother/slower scroll!
    window.scrollTo(0, c - c / 10);
  }
};

// When the button is clicked, run our ScrolltoTop function above!
scrollToTopButton.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  scrollToTop();
}
```

But every time I add smooth scrolling to make the user experience better:

```
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

the back-to-top button glitches.

Ideally, I would like the back-to-top button to scroll smooth as well as the rest of the content on the page (e.g. anchor links in the navigation that link to sections on the same page).

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome 77, and in fact for me it does not glitch, it completely prevents scrolling. I then tried to add `scroll-behavior` to the `body` instead of `html`, and it seems to work... Can you confirm? https://jsfiddle.net/L7pwa0rg/2/

Comment: You could try using `<a name="top" />` and `<a href="#top">Go to top</a>` instead.

Comment: I added ```scroll-behaviour``` to the ```body``` instead of ```html``` and it made the back-to-top button scroll smooth but not the rest of the page. For example, if I have an anchor in the navigation that links to a section on the page it does not smooth-scroll there when I add it to ```body``` @blex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're to have smooth back to top this should help.

```js
// Set a variable for our button element.
const scrollToTopButton = document.getElementById('js-top');
smoothScrollCapture = (x) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = event.target.getAttribute('href').split("#")[1]
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  var x = el.getBoundingClientRect().left
  var y = el.getBoundingClientRect().top
  smoothScrollFunc(x, y)
}

smoothScrollFunc = (x, y) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  window.scrollTo({
    top: y,
    left: x,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  scrollToTopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    smoothScrollFunc(0, 0)
  })

  var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('A')
  var myTags = []
  for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
    if (aTags[i].getAttribute("href").indexOf('#') === 0) {
      aTags[i].addEventListener('click', smoothScrollCapture);
    }
  }
})

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  // Get the current scroll value
  let y = window.scrollY;
  if (y > 100) {
    scrollToTopButton.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    scrollToTopButton.style.display = 'none'
  }
})
```

```css
#js-top {
  position: fixed;
  /*OR WHATEVER YOU PREFER*/
  bottom: 10px;
  /*OR WHEREVER YOU PREFER*/
  left: 50%;
  /*OR WHEREVER YOU PREFER*/
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 1000px;">
  <div class="nav-items">
    <a href="#paragraph1">Paragraph One</a>
    <a href="#paragraph2">Paragraph Two</a>
    <a href="#paragraph3">Paragraph Three</a>
    <a href="#paragraph4">Paragraph Four</a>
  </div>

  <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
  <p id="paragraph1">Here is the first paragraph!</p>
  <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
  <p id="paragraph2">Here is the second paragraph!</p>
  <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
  <p id="paragraph3">Here is the third paragraph!</p>
  <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
  <p id="paragraph4">Here is the fourth paragraph!</p>
</div>

<button id='js-top'>Scroll To Top</button>
```

**EDIT**
I've updated the code snippet. There might be a solution using just CSS but I have been unable to figure it out. Using JavaScript, I essentially capture all of the `a` tags with an `href` that is the `id` of another element and apply the `smoothScrollCapture` function to it.

I figured this would be easier for you rather than going into your HTML and giving all page nav items a new unique class.

In `smoothScrollCapture`, when you click a nav item (say, `paragraph3`) you capture the `id` from the click event (the target's `href`) and then use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the `top` and `left` values. Since you're doing this in the click function it should be responsive to resizing of the page. Then you pass those values to `smoothScrollFunc` which simply applies those `x` and `y` values to the `window.scrollTo` function.

I've also wrapped all the initialization code in a DOMContentLoaded event listener for good measure. These initialization measures include getting `a` tags and applying `smoothScrollCapture` to them, as well as adding the click event to `scrollToTopButton` and passing 0 for the `x` and `y` values since it's just going to the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - just made a edit because I think I didn't word it precisely enough. I would like to also have the rest of the page scroll smoothly (e.g anchor links from the navigation bar linking to sections within the page). If I have the smooth scroll enabled on the html it makes the page items scroll smooth but makes the back-to-top button glitch.

Comment: @Lisa I've updated the code snippet to apply the smooth scroll function to all elements that have an `href` that is an `id` of another element on the page. You could also just give all nav items a unique class to serve this similar purpose but figured getting the href would be easier than added a new class to x amount of items in your HTML. There may a CSS solution for this but I have been unable to find it and this solution seems to work fine.